# number of rows in big table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM BigTable_1
```

Which way I should to use to get number of rows in table if I have more than 1 billion of rows?

UPDATE: For example, if we have 'a timeout problem' with the query above is there any way to optimize it?  How to do it quicker?

Comment: You answered your own question... @_@

Comment: Are you asking this because `COUNT(*)` is too slow and you're looking for a faster alternative? You really should specify that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need an exact count, you have to use `COUNT (*)`

If you are OK with a rough count, you can use a sum of rows in the partitions

```
SELECT SUM (Rows)
FROM sys.partitions
WHERE 1=1
And index_id IN (0, 1)
And OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('Database.schema.Table');
```

If you want to be funny with your `COUNT`, you can do the following

```
select COUNT (1/0) from BigTable_1
```

Comment: What does "sum of rows in the partition(s)" mean/imply?

Comment: @pst if the table is partitioned, it will grab the row count for all partitions.

Comment: @Ben Thul - As long as you have the requisite permissions on the table / columns, the SQL Server Optimizer ignores whatever is inside the parenthesis in a `COUNT ()`

Answer (score 4):

A very fast ESTIMATE:

select count(*) from table

But don't execute!  Highlight the code, press ctl-l to bring up the query plan.  Then hover over the leftmost arrow.  A yellow box appears with the estimated number of rows.

You can query system tables to get the same data, but that is harder to remember.  This way is much more impressive to onlookers.

:)

Comment: +1 For being clever/different. But I believe bonkered statistics can throw this way off ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [sys.dm_db_partition_stats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187737.aspx).

```
select sum(row_count)
from sys.dm_db_partition_stats
where object_id = object_id('TableName') and  index_id < 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your concurrency, speed, and accuracy requirements, you can get an *approximate* answer with triggers. Create a table

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_COUNTS(TABLE_NAME VARCHAR, R_COUNT BIGINT DEFAULT 0); 
INSERT INTO TABLE_COUNTS('BigTable_1', 0);
```

(I'm going to leave out adding a key, etc., for brevity.)

Now set up triggers.

```
CREATE TRIGGER bt1count_1 AFTER INSERT ON BigTable_1 FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
UPDATE TABLE_COUNTS SET R_COUNT=R_COUNT+1 WHERE TABLE_NAME='BigTable_1';
END;
```

A corresponding decrement trigger goes on DELETEs. Now instead of a COUNT, you query the TABLE_COUNT table. Your result will be a little off in the case of pending transactions, but you may be able to live with that. And the cost is amortized over all of the INSERT and DELETE operations; getting the row count when you need it is fast.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select sum(P.rows) from sys.partitions P with (nolock)      
join sys.tables T with (nolock) on P.object_id = T.object_id        
where T.Name = 'Table_1' and index_id = 1
```

it should be a lot faster. Got it from here: [SELECT COUNT(*) FOR BIG TABLE](http://dwbi1.wordpress.com/2010/11/12/select-count-for-big-table/)

Comment: Does this have/imply/impose any sort of accuracy? (Assuming no concurrent transactions for simplicity.)

Comment: @pst: the rows column isn't updated in real time in sys.partitions; it will only be a rough estimate.  But on a table with 1G rows, it's like the old joke: is the temperature of the sun a few million degrees C or degrees F?  Answer: does it matter?

Comment: @Ben - It is updated pretty much in real time from tests I've done in the past. Indeed one criticism of it might be that it has the effect of uncommitted transactions, it also counts forwarding pointers in the heap and [can be manually altered](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/ben_nevarez/archive/2010/01/13/fooling-the-query-optimizer.aspx)

Comment: All I'm saying is that BOL says of this column: "Approximate number of rows in this partition".  Take that for what it's worth.

Comment: @Ben - Indeed. My comment did give 3 other reasons why it could be inaccurate!

Answer (score 0):

Your query will get the number of rows regardless of the quantity.  Try using the query you listed in your question.

Comment: Actually if they have many more than 2 billion rows they will need to use `COUNT_BIG` instead.

Answer (score 0):

There's only 1 [accurate] way to count the rows in a table: `count(*)`. `sp_spaceused` or looking at the statistics won't necessarily give you the [a?] correct answer.

Answer (score -2):

if you've got a primary key you should be able to do this:

select count(PrimaryKey) from table_1

Comment: I'm not going to down-vote, but the column supplied to `COUNT(...)` should be irrelevant to the query optimizer -- e.g. `COUNT(*)` doesn't have to do more work than `COUNT(x)` as the tuples themselves (independent upon columns they contain) in the result set are counted.

Comment: @pst - Only true for `NON NULL` columns of course. In SQL Server `COUNT(PK)`, `COUNT(*)`, `COUNT(1)`, `COUNT(any NON NULL column)` all get converted to `COUNT(*)` in the execution plan. There is no difference betweeen them.

Comment: The only difference here is whether SQL server needs to query the schema first before counting the tuples, which might be the case with COUNT(*). It won't impact the number of rows, but might impact the speed of execution. It does depend on the version of the SQL server in this case.