# Error of check a big table row number

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows-7, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table on SQL Server 2008 R2 on win7.

It is 130 GB.

It has 4.5 billion rows, which is got by checking table property.

But, if I use `COUNT(*)` to get row number, I got error:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

My SQL query:

```
SELECT CAST(COUNT(*) AS BIGINT) AS total_row_num
FROM [my_db].[dbo].[my_table]
```

The solution at 
[number of rows in big table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747396/number-of-rows-in-big-table)
does not work for me. I need to get the exact number of rows.

Also, `COUNT(*)` runs very slow for big table, are there faster ways ?

Thanks

Comment: Use COUNT_BIG instead of COUNT.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190317.aspx

Comment: So, let's think about this. You are going to manually count 4.5 billion rows. It needs to be "exact" so you place a SELECT on the table under the default isolation level (or maybe you even escalate it). Meanwhile, surely, other users are trying to do things to this table - insert, delete, update, merge, etc. They are blocked by your select. So by the time your select finishes reading all 130GB of data to get a count, you have this queue of operations that are going to - surprise - change the count. How useful is that "accurate" count now?

Comment: So if *exact*, *to-the-microsecond* accuracy is not as important as you claim, use the metadata like `sys.partitions` - pretty accurate, non-blocking, and fast. And if concurrency isn't an issue (e.g. you don't have this class of users competing with your count to change the table), the metadata will be pretty darned accurate. You need to determine what's important: fast or page-read accuracy. You can't have both.

Comment: http://www.bimonkey.com/2009/06/count-the-number-of-rows-in-every-table-in-a-database-in-no-time/

Comment: If you really **must** have the exact number of rows, make sure you have some index on a small, non-nullable column (preferably an `INT NOT NULL`) column so that the counting can be done on a very small index (instead of actually enumerating the table's data pages!)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the BIGINT version of COUNT:

```
SELECT COUNT_BIG(1) FROM [my_db].[dbo].[my_table];
```

I just used this on a table with a hundred million rows, and it returned nearly instantly.  I don't have a handy table with over four billion rows to test on, but it should be pretty fast as long as your table is properly indexed with a clustered primary key.

Answer (score 0):

A faster way is to call `sp_spaceused`:

```
EXEC sp_spaceused 'my_table'
```

Documentation about the stored procedure: [Microsoft Developer Network](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188776.aspx)